# Amazon EMR Tunneling Zeppelin and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am running Spark EMR on Amazon EC2 and I am trying to tunnel Jupyter Notebook and Zeppelin, so I can access them locally.

I tried running the below command with no success:

```
ssh -i ~/user.pem -ND 8157 hadoop@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

What exactly is tunnelling and how can I set it up so I can use Jupyter Notebook and Zeppelin on EMR?

Is there a way to I set up a basic configuration to make this work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application ports like 8890, for Zeppelin on the master node, are not exposed outside of the cluster.  So, if you are trying to access the notebook from your laptop, it will not work.  SSH tunneling is a way to access these ports via SSH, securely.  You are missing at least one step outlined in [Set Up an SSH Tunnel to the Master Node Using Dynamic Port Forwarding](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel.html).  Specifically, "After the tunnel is active, configure a SOCKS proxy for your browser."

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that I need to configure proxy settings with FoxyProxy. Do you have any idea how to edit the settings.xml file here so it can be used with Zepellin and Jupyter Notebook? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node-proxy.html

Comment: You shouldn't need to add any.  I use Zeppelin and only use three URL pattern matchers in FoxyProxy: ec2*.amazonaws.com*, \*ec2*.compute*, and \*.ec2.internal*.  Be sure that your VPC has "DNS hostnames" enabled, otherwise you may need to add IPs to the URL pattern matcher.